# Email-to-Case: where can I find the ThreadID?

Tags: email2case

Suppose that I have received a Case from a mail sent from example@example.com.
Suppose that I have *enabled* the ThreadID on Setup--> Customize--> Case--> Email-to-Case.

Then, when I am on the Case created on my org, where can I see the **ThreadID**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread Ids are generated only for outbound emails from within the case. 
Since you have enabled thread ids, you should start seeing them on the Email related list once you send out emails regarding the case.

The thread ID will be in the form: **ref:XXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX:ref**

Read more about it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005080&language=en_US)

Comment: More on this here :: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000330749&type=1&mode=1

"If you are using case auto replies, make sure to add the thread Id to the email template you are using in either the subject line, the body, or both. To include the thread Id, edit your email template, select Field Type "Case Fields", then select the field "Case Thread Id". You can type the merge field {!Case.Thread_Id} in your email template."

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Thread_id is not exposed by Salesforce. But still, if you want to see the ThreadID on the Case record, you can create a formula field.

Please visit link for formula, https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006trk

Regards,
Sandesh Ganjare